# Using a html.validationmessagefor for a client side error message

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, client-side-validation

I have server side validation messages for some of my text fields. The field 'title' is a required field server side with a '[Required]' data attribute in the class, but this only seems to get checked on a postback or form submit. I'm saving the 'title' text field on a jquery .change event, sudo code below. But I want to use my validationmessagefor to show the error message from the client side check. Not sure how to go about doing this?

html.

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Overview.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

rendered as

```
<span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Overview.Title" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

If I want to do some client side checking in javascript and then use this  element to display a client side error message can I do so. I'm just trying to save myself of using another hidden element. I know I would have to use

> data-valmsg-for="Overview.Title"

because the other data attributes are the same for all the other text fields.

Whats the best way to do display client side error messages here if I want to check to make sure the "title" has length greater then 1?

Maybe something like -

```js
$('#Overview_Title').change(function() {
    var title = $(this).val();
    if (title.length == 0) {
      // show error message "title has to be a value to save"
      }
    else {
      // do other work like save to db
      }
  });
```

Comment: Does your client-side validation only trigger on submit or does it never fire at all?

Comment: it never fires because I don't have any client-side validation yet. This particular page doesn't have any form submit or any save button. Everything gets saved on jquery .change() events.

Comment: So what I'm looking to do is, when the change event happens I do the check for a value, if none exists because the user removed/deleted the value from the text field then I will display an error message saying 'value required' to make a change'

Comment: Where do you do the change event? which control?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got a few ways to do this but I'd argue that this is the easiest way:

MVC will by default bundle the `jquery.validate` javascript library into your page. Since you are already marking the field with the `[Required]` attribute, the `Html.EditorFor` will bind the correct attributes into your HTML for you so that validation can happen as necessary.

To make your current logic work with the smallest changes, you could add a `<form>` tag around your input field(s). I think you need this for the `validate` method to work out of the box. Then your javascript would change to something like this:

```
$('#Overview_Title').change(function() {
if ($(this).valid()) {
  // do your stuff
  }
else {
  // error message displayed automatically. don't need to do anything here unless you want to
  }
});
```

This would allow you to use the `Required` attribute to set your error message text and your `ValidationMessageFor` should display the error message without any extra effort on your part.

Check out this plunkr as a proof of concept: http://plnkr.co/edit/ip04s3dOPqI9YNKRCRDZ?p=preview

**EDIT**

I'm not positive I understand your follow-up question. But if you wanted to add a rule to a field dynamically, you could do something along these lines:

```
$( "#someinput" ).rules( "add", {
 required: true,
 messages: {
 required: "a value is required to save changes"
 }
});
```

You could add rules that aren't reflected server side by doing something like this. Then you could validate that input in the same way.

Comment: this works! but lets say I have a summary text field and it can be empty, so there is no '[required]' attribute, BUT if there is a value in it and the user removes it and it's blank and then the change is triggered to save, I need it to say something like 'a value  is required to save changes'. How would that work?

Comment: @user1186050 You can add `rules` that are only on the client if they aren't reflected in your model. I edited my answer to show what that may look like.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do 100% client side validation using jquery you can use something like this:

```
$('#Overview_ISBN').on('input', function() {
    var input=$('#Overview_Title');
    var is_name=input.val();
    if(is_name){input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");}
    else{input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");}
});
```

Here's the code of [JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/dpb7cujk/1/)

In the example i posted , if you start typing the ISBN and the Title is empty, you will get the error message.

Not sure in your question how you want to trigger the error so i assumed it's an entry in a different input

Comment: 100% client sided validation is bad and cannot be trusted.